# Programatically set the background of a Node image to a color

Tags: c#, wpf, image, background, treeview

The code below generates a treeview node with an Icon (from a .PNG file Piconfolder\PiconName) followed by a Text string Pheader.
I want to add a background to just the icon (to be used with transparent icons)

```
public static TreeViewItem CreateTreeViewItem(
         string Pheader,
         string PiconFolder,
         string PiconName)
    {
        string iconFolder = PiconFolder;
        string iconName = PiconName;
        string header = Pheader;
        TreeViewItem child = new TreeViewItem();
        StackPanel pan = new StackPanel();
        pan.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        string fPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(iconFolder, iconName);
        Image image = new Image();
        image.Height = 16;
        image.Width = 16;
        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fPath,  uriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        pan.Children.Add(image);                             
        pan.Children.Add(new TextBlock(new Run("  " + header)));
        child.Header = pan;  
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
pan.Children.Add(image);
```

with

```
var iconPanel = new Grid(); // or other panel
iconPanel.Background = Brushes.Blue;
iconPanel.Children.Add(image);
pan.Children.Add(iconPanel);
```